# How to fix invalid vertex id error in tidygraph?

Tags: r, igraph, tidygraph

**Data**

```
network_data <- list(nodes = structure(list(id = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), label = c("2892056", "2894543", "2894544", 
"2894545", "2894546", "2894547", "2894548", "2894549", "2894550", 
"2894551", "2894552", "2894553", "2894554", "2894555", "2894556"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame"), links = structure(list(
    from = c(3, 5, 7, 13, 13, 7, 3, 5, 0, 0, 5, 2, 7, 6, 13, 
    11, 0, 3, 2, 7, 13, 3, 0, 0, 5, 3, 13, 4, 0, 14, 13, 7, 2, 
    3, 5, 0, 12), to = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 11, 12, 12, 
    12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14), weight = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -37L
), class = "data.frame"))
```

I have this list of nodes and links for building a network. Rather than plotting the network, I want to get the network characteristics such as `isolates`, `reciprocity`, etc.

Here's the rest of the code that I'm using to obtain these characteristics:

```
network_data$nodes <- network_data$nodes %>% select(id, label)
  
  network_data$links <- network_data$links %>% rename(from = source, to = target)
  
  print(network_data$nodes)
  print(network_data$links)
  
  SNA <- tidygraph::tbl_graph(
    nodes = network_data$nodes, 
    edges = network_data$links, 
    directed = T
  )
```

The last line is where it errors out.

```
Error in (function (edges, n = max(edges), directed = TRUE)  : 
  At structure_generators.c:86 : Invalid (negative) vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

I googled the issue and seems like it's pretty prevalent, but none of the methods suggested worked for me. What's different in my data that it's still generating the error, and how can I resolve this error?

Comment: My first guess is that the vertex id `0` is not allowed. You could try adding `+1` to each vertex id

Comment: That was it. I thought I read somewhere that the `igraph` is 0 based so I created `id` as 0 based. I suppose I read it wrong. Thanks @BenNutzer for helping me out.

Comment: I think that you were not so wrong.  In python, I think the first node is 0. In R it is 1.